# Apply different templates depending on screen resolution

Tags: django-cms

What is the best practice to show different content for different screen resolutions in django-cms? I'd like to use different templates. @media in the css can't help much.

Comment: What's wrong with media queries?

Comment: Nothing, media will work but one always seeks easy way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3260061 What about using some sort of a frontend framework like Bootstrap or Foundation - they are all using [media queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) to do it for you.

P.S.
...sorry I didn't realize your were talking about changing templates. It's not just about changing style / layout. I generally doubt that it is possible to do in an elegant way - in fact you will have to make two separate page versions with separate URLs and switch between them after obtaining the media query data. I might be mistaken though...